# parameterizing py.test fixture objects

Tags: python, pytest

I have looked at the py.test documentation and so far have been ok. I have tests / test fixtures like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def comm_env():
    return CommEnv()

def test_write1(comm_env):
'''Write patterns and read them back.'''
    ... fun stuff goes here ...
```

so that I can create a custom `CommEnv()` object and my tests can get access to it.

Now I need to add a command-line parameter to the `comm_env()` function so I can pass in a communications port name and baud rate. How can I do this? I looked at the [parametrizing test fixtures](http://pytest.org/latest/parametrize.html) page but my eyes just glaze over.

I did figure out how to [add command-line arguments](http://pytest.org/latest/example/simple.html) by adding a short `conftest.py` file in the test directory, but I can't figure out how to connect it to make it available to `comm_env()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out: you can access the `config` attribute of the fixture [`request`](http://pytest.org/latest/builtin.html#_pytest.python.FixtureRequest) object:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def comm_env(request):
    commport = request.config.getoption('--port')
    baudrate = request.config.getoption('--baud')
    print "params: %s, %s" % (commport, baudrate)
    return CommEnv(commport, baudrate)
```

and then I just have to do this in the conftest.py:

```
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--port',help='serial port e.g. COM1')
    parser.addoption('--baud',help='baud rate',type=int)
```

Comment: Suggestion: no provided default values in pytest_addoption so you may need to test the values in comm_env s.t you have expected behavior when user provides no params to cli, unless CommEnv implicitly handles __init__(None, None). Alternatively, return None from comm_env fixture and test handles that case too, or is marked 'skip' by other mechanisms that auto-skip fixture comm_env response None.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [this section](http://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html#fixture-parametrize) which means it would become:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", params=[
    (123, 456),
    (456, 789),
])
def comm_env(request):
    val1, val2 = request.param
    return CommEnv()
```

You can construct the fixture when you have `params = [(123, 456), (456, 789)]`:

```
def construct_fixture(params):
    @pytest.fixture(scope="session", params=params)
    def comm_env(request):
        val1, val2 = request.param
        return CommEnv()
    return comm_env

globals()['comm_env'] = construct_fixture(params)
```

Comment: No, I don't want to take parameters hard-coded from the script; I want to take them from the command line.

Comment: @JasonS: construct the fixture using a function and the parameters from the command-line, return it and add it to the global namespace?

Comment: Simeon: I guess what you say sounds reasonable but I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @JasonS: I have updated my answer (untested). You'll need to construct `params` from the command-line but after that you can create the fixture dynamically.